# Manipulating one of the values of a vector of pairs in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, std-pair

If I have a vector of doubles *PMF* I can divide all elements of the vector by a double *count* by using the transform command as follows:

```
transform(PMF.begin(),PMF.end(),PMF.begin(),bind2nd(divides<double>(),count));
```

Now however, I have a vector of unsigned char/double pairs:

```
vector<pair<unsigned char, double>> PMF
```

I wish to replace the double values by their values divided by *count*. I haven't been able to find a way to do this using the transform command or any other C++11 functionality. Does anyone have an idea as to how to do this?

Comment: `bind2nd` is deprecated in c++11

Comment: `for_each` is nice, with a functor (a lambda?) that modifies the second element.

Comment: I think you are over-complicating it. Range-based for loop is simpler solution. `for(auto& p: PMF) p.second /= count;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lambda function as same as this:

```
transform(PMF.begin(),
          PMF.end(),
          PMF.begin(),
          [count](const pair<unsigned char, double> &x)
          {
             return make_pair(x.first, x.second/count);
          });
```

or

```
for_each(PMF.begin(),
         PMF.end(),
         [count](pair<unsigned char, double>& x)
         {
            x.second /= count;
         });
```

or

```
for (auto &x : PMF)
  x.second /= count;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the everlasting discussion of std-algorithms vs. range based for. Personally, I prefer the std-algorithms, because they can be easily replace with parallel versions and because I think that they show the intent immediately. Though, Boost Range is of course better than std.